# jScrollPane contentPane not reinitialising when img src changes

Tags: jscrollpane

My objective is to load dynamically various landscape panoramic images into the jScrollPane container and reinitialise so that the scrollbar would be re-calculated based on the current img dimensions.

My problem is that although I'm injecting the img src and then calling the api.reinitialise() method, it's not updating. Therefore the img loads, but the scrolling pane is still the same width.

I'm assume it has something to do with jScrollPane not being able to retrieve the new img dimensions in time to reinitialise with the right width.

HTML

```
<div class="px-content">
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var scrollPane = $('.px-content').jScrollPane({hideFocus: true, showArrows: true, autoReinitialise: true});
var api = scrollPane.data('jsp');       

 var loadImage = function(id){
            var image, $paneContent, $img;
            imageSource= this.get(id); // returns an image URL



$paneContent = this.jspAPI.getContentPane();
        $img = $paneContent.find('img').attr('src', imageSource);
        api.reinitialise();
    }

loadImage(0); // loads correctly
loadImage(1); // loads img correctly, but pane doesn't refresh to new width
```

Any ideas? Happy to try anything.

Seb.